# Does MODIFY retain other column attributes in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb, ddl

Taking this example from the MariaDB knowledgebase:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  a INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
  b VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY b VARCHAR(40);
```

1. Will `b` still be `NOT NULL` after this statement?
2. Will `b` still have a uniqueness constraint attached to it?

Assume the latest release of MariaDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing this myself, I concluded that:

1. `b` will not retain the `NOT NULL` attribute; this is reset to the default of allowing nulls.
2. The uniqueness constraint remains.

Apparently I also completely overlooked the fact that the knowledgebase explains this behavior: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#modify-column

Comment: Think of it this way: (1) indexing is separate from column definition, but (2) attributes must be specified when `MODIFYing` (or `CHANGEing`) a column.